# Debug GWT Rcp Failure without errors

Tags: gwt, rpc, gxt

I really cannot solve this problem!
I've got a gwt/gxt project getting an error and thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193373/best-practices-for-gwt-services-exceptions-logging) post I could put as many "handle" as possible.
This is the code where I call the rpc:

```
Button bSave=new Button("Save", new SelectionListener<ButtonEvent>() {  
   @Override 
   public void componentSelected(ButtonEvent ce) {
          //creation of parameters
          List<CodeBaseModel> rapportino =new ArrayList<CodeBaseModel>();
          CodeBaseModel rapp = new CodeBaseModel(getValues());
          List<CodeBaseModel> tmp =new ArrayList<CodeBaseModel>();
          tmp.add(rapp);
          snd_service.saveData(tmp, new AsyncCallback<Boolean>(){
             public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        Window.alert(caught.getMessage());
        Window.alert(getStackTrace(caught, "\n"));
             }
         public void onSuccess(List<CodeBaseModel> result) {
        //control results
                ...
             }
          });
     }
});
```

I got no error on server side, and the function is never executed. 
In Chrome I could not see the request to the server service. 
I use exactly the same function of the same Asynchronous class in another point of my code and it works fine (I call it in the same way). 
I got no javascript or other client side errors. 
The failure caught object returns no information:  
caught.getMessage() -> undefined  
getStackTrace(caught, "\n") -> Unknown.Qic(Unknown source:0) Unknown.uqc(Unknown source:0) Unknown.yqc(Unknown source:0) Unknown.Rnc(Unknown source:0) Unknown.$D(Unknown source:0) Unknown.Gqc(Unknown source:0) Unknown.yqc(Unknown source:0)  

I don't know what to do, any suggestion?  

Thanks, Federica

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to answer my question but finally I found out where there was the problem. I see it doesn't interest anyone but I don't trust so much in myself and I'm quite sure I'll fall into this issue again, so...
The problem was due to the values of the parameter passed to the Asynchronous function call; for a miswrite error, one of this values was a client user defined object.

Bye, Federica