# GWT Remote Logging could not log Throwable Stacktrace?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, servlets, grails

I want to use GWT [Remote Logging](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html). This is what I did:

In my web.xml file I did:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>remoteLogging</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.gwt.logging.server.RemoteLoggingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>remoteLogging</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/web/remote_logging</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

In my gwt.xml file I did:

```
 <module rename-to='web'>

 ...    

 <inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging" />
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="INFO" />
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE" />
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.popupHandler" value="DISABLED" />
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.developmentModeHandler" value="ENABLED" />  
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler" value="ENABLED" />
```

And somewhere in my GWT Java code I did:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("NameOfYourLogger");
logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "this message should get logged");
```

But, when I try to log the stack trace (Throwable) like this:

```
// Throwable throwable

LogRecord lr = new LogRecord(Level.SEVERE, "test");
lr.setThrown(throwable);
logger.log(lr);
```

I get an error:

```
16:24:26.887 [ERROR] [web] Sun Feb 09 16:24:26 CET 2014 WireActivityLogger
SEVERE: Remote logging failed: 
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SerializableThrowable cannot be cast to com.google.gwt.core.shared.SerializableThrowable
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException_FieldSerializer.instantiate(IncompatibleRemoteServiceException_FieldSerializer.java:16)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException_FieldSerializer.create(IncompatibleRemoteServiceException_FieldSerializer.java:25)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.instantiate(SerializerBase.java:115)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ClientSerializationStreamReader.java:396)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamReader.readObject(AbstractSerializationStreamReader.java:119)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:216)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:258)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:412)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor103.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor101.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**How can I remote log the stacktrace?**

Edit: I also tried

```
// Throwable throwable
LogRecord lr = new LogRecord(Level.SEVERE, throwable.toString());
logger.log(lr);
```

and

```
// Throwable throwable
LogRecord lr = new LogRecord(Level.SEVERE, throwable.getMessage());
logger.log(lr);
```

but I got the following error:

```
| Error 2014-02-19 02:21:04,017 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] ERROR [localhost].[/test]  - Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
Message: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String com.google.gwt.logging.shared.RemoteLoggingService.logOnServer(java.util.logging.LogRecord)' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    Line | Method
->>  389 | encodeResponseForFailure in com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    579 | invokeAndEncodeResponse  in     ''
|    265 | processCall . . . . . .  in com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet
|    305 | processPost              in     ''
|     62 | doPost . . . . . . . . . in com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet
|     46 | doFilterInternal         in org.grails.jaxrs.web.JaxrsFilter
|     70 | doFilter . . . . . . . . in com.github.greengerong.PreRenderSEOFilter
|   1145 | runWorker                in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run                      in java.lang.Thread
Caused by NullPointerException: null
->>  262 | hash                     in java.util.Hashtable
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    459 | get                      in     ''
|    489 | findLogger . . . . . . . in java.util.logging.LogManager$LoggerContext
|    910 | getLogger                in java.util.logging.LogManager
|    400 | demandLogger . . . . . . in     ''
|    317 | demandLogger             in java.util.logging.Logger
|    361 | getLogger . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     62 | logOnServer              in com.google.gwt.logging.server.RemoteLoggingServiceUtil
|     46 | logOnServer . . . . . .  in com.google.gwt.logging.server.RemoteLoggingServiceImpl
|    561 | invokeAndEncodeResponse  in com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC
|    265 | processCall . . . . . .  in com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet
|    305 | processPost              in     ''
|     62 | doPost . . . . . . . . . in com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet
|     46 | doFilterInternal         in org.grails.jaxrs.web.JaxrsFilter
|     70 | doFilter . . . . . . . . in com.github.greengerong.PreRenderSEOFilter
|   1145 | runWorker                in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run                      in java.lang.Thread
```

Edit:

This is my code that I use:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

new AsyncCallback<GetResults<ItemDto>>() {


            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
                Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("test");
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "this message should get logged");

                LogRecord lr = new LogRecord(Level.SEVERE, e.toString());
                logger.log(lr);

            }

            ...

}
```

Comment: `InvocationException:` And then what? What is the name of your module (according to your web.xml it should be `web`)? Any output in your server log?

Comment: @ColinAlworth I updated my question logging works for Strings but not for Throwable as I pointed out. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the exception when casting the SerializableThrowable from the client.impl library to the core.shared library. It seems like you just want the issue to be written to the log as a string.  I've never used this class (just reading from the documentation), have you tried the following ...

```
// Throwable throwable
LogRecord lr = new LogRecord(Level.SEVERE, throwable.toString());
logger.log(lr);
```

or

```
// Throwable throwable
LogRecord lr = new LogRecord(Level.SEVERE, throwable.getMessage());
logger.log(lr);
```

if this doesn't work, you may find the following links helpful:

http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2012/06/11/7-tips-for-exception-handling-in-gwt/

Note that in the URL above, in Tip 4, the author sets his program up identically to yours.  But he cautions in the last paragraph that ....

> "[Log exceptions on the server] seems straight-forward, right? Be careful! First, not all exceptions
>   are serializable or follow the rules of serializable (ugh!). For
>   example, GWT’s JavascriptException inherits Serializable, but doesn’t
>   implement a public no-arg constructor, so when you try to send this
>   over the wire via your RPC, a run-time Serialization exception is
>   thrown. And since this exception would be thrown inside your exception
>   handler, it would effectively swallowed. Second, the stack trace
>   within an exception is transient, and so [it] is lost from client to server
>   (so if you need it on the server side, send it as a separate
>   parameter). Which leads me to the next tip…"

In the paragraph he states the exact original problem you were having - not all exceptions are serializable so a Serialization exception may be thrown (which might also explain why the throwable object is null when you are trying to ouput the thrown error's message from the AsyncCallback class' onFailure method).  Then go on to read tip number 5 and 6.

These links may also be useful ...

[Best Practices for GWT services exceptions logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193373/best-practices-for-gwt-services-exceptions-logging)

http://cleancodematters.com/2011/05/29/improved-exceptionhandling-with-gwts-requestfactory/

Comment: I tried your solution but it failed. I posted the error in my question. Any other idea?

Comment: @confile is there a Throwable object named thowable defined as your comment points out? sounds like it is null and when it is being added as the second parameter of LogRecord it is causing a nullpointer exception.

Comment: I posted the code I am using. the Throwable is not null.

Comment: @confile, see my edited answer which includes an excerpt from the URL that I originally posted which you may find helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Consider logging exception stack traces:

```
<set-property name="compiler.stackMode"   
     value="emulated" />  
<set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordLineNumbers"   
     value="true"/>   
<set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordFileNames"   
     value="true"/>
```

stacktrace and exception handling are following as:

1. http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2012/06/11/7-tips-for-exception-handling-in-gwt/
2. https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WebModeExceptions

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error you get, it seems that your GWT app is sending instances of `com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SerializableThrowable` but your server is expecting instances of `com.google.gwt.core.shared.SerializableThrowable`.

In our project we are still using GWT 2.5 and the class we have in the SDK is the first one.

It seems that GWT 2.6 introduced the second one and deprecated the other. Maybe your client and your server are not on the exact same version of GWT? Or you have client code that uses the wrong SerializableThrowable somehow.

Also, here are two properties I noticed that we have but you don't mention in the GWT config:

```
<set-property name="compiler.stackMode" value="emulated" />
<set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordLineNumbers" value="true" />
```